# H2 Database File Size is too big (7x larger than expected)

Tags: java, database, h2

I was keeping my data in ascii text files (like 100 files). Data Structure is same. Per file per stock data. 
The total file size was 220 MB.

I decided to switch to a database, (and because my program is in java i decided to use H2 database).

When I save my data to the H2 database the DB file size is 1.6 GB. 
I have got only 2 tables one is for Stocks (ticker, name), other is Stock_Daily_Transactions(ticker, date, open, high, low, close, volume).

The question is if it is normal to have almost 8 times larger file size for keeping it in database. To me it looks like there is a problem with H2.

I am planning to use Derby database instead of H2 and see the results, but any opinion would be appreciated before doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Databases store all sorts of information, for example indexes, in the tables. This allows the queries to run very fast, as opposed to searching the whole file. Yes, it is normal. It will be exacerbated if you have unnecessary indexes.

Comment: Which version of H2 did you try with? If you tried with version 1.4.x (beta), could you also try with the "old" file format, by appending ";mv_store=false" to the database URL?

Comment: Yes, i am using 1.4.x version. After reading your comment i have tried your suggestion and now DB file size is 830 MB.